# Images in Web application

Tags: web

I am working on application in which users will upload huge number of images and i have to show those image webpage

What is the best way to store and retrieve images.

1) Database
2) FileSystem
3) CDN
4) JCR
or something else

What i know is
Database: saving and retrieving image from database will lead to lot of queries to database and will convert blob to file everytime. I think it will degrade the website performance

FileSystem: If i keep image information in database and image file in filesystem there will be sync issues. Like if i took a backup of the database we do have take the backup of images folder. ANd if there are millions of files it will consume lot of server resources
i read it here
http://akashkava.com/blog/127/huge-file-storage-in-database-instead-of-file-system/

Another options are CDNs and JCR

Please suggest the best option

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Using the File System is only really an option if you only plan to deploy to one server (i.e. not several behind a load balancer), OR if all of your servers will have access to a shared File System. It may also be inefficient, unless you cache frequently-accessed files in the application server.

You're right that storing the actual binary data in a Database is perhaps overkill, and not what databases do best.

I'd suggest a combination:

- A CDN (such as AWS CloudFront), backed by a publicly-accessible (but crucially publicly read-only) storage such as Amazon S3 would mean that your images are efficiently served, wherever the browsing user is located and cached appropriately in their browser (thus minimising bandwidth). S3 (or similar) means you have an API to upload and manage them from your application servers, without worrying about how all servers (and the outside world) will access them.
- I'd suggest perhaps holding meta data about each image in a Database however. This means that you could assign each image a unique key (generated by your database), add extra info (file format, size, tags, author, etc), and also store the path to S3 (or similar) via the CDN as the publicly-accessible path to the image.

This combination of Database and shared publicly-accessible storage is probably a good mix, giving you the best of both worlds. The Database also means that if you need to move / change or bulk delete images in future (perhaps deleting all images uploaded by an author who is deleting their account), you can perform an efficient Database query to gather metadata, followed by updating / changing the stored images at the S3 locations the Database says they exist.

You say you want to display the images on a web page. This combination means that the application server can query the database efficiently for the image selection you want to show (including restricting by author, pagination, etc), then generate a view containing images referring to the correct CDN path. It means viewing the images is also quite efficient as you combine dynamic content (the page upon which the images are shown) with static content (the image themselves via the CDN).

Answer (score 0):

CDNs may be a good option for you.

You can store the link to the images along with the image information in  your database.